# Setting Origin of Animation to center of View

Tags: ios, swift

I have an animation that I'm trying to position in the center of the view. Here's my current code set at static values:

```
imageViewAnimatedFrame.origin.x = 10
imageViewAnimatedFrame.origin.y = 200
imageViewAnimatedFrame.size.height = 298
imageViewAnimatedFrame.size.width = 391
```

I'm pretty new to Swift. Is there a way to set the origin x and y to the center subtracted by half the width and height so it lays in the center?
Thanks!

Comment: You may wish to look at the `center` property of `UIView`.

Comment: When I say UIView.center it says you can't use center with UIView. When I do view.center as I did somewhere else in my code it says "Cannot assign value of type "CGPoint" to type "CGFloat"

Comment: It would be clearer if you updated your question with relevant code showing how you are trying to use and set the center.

Comment: x pos will be center of super  view.x.  - (widthOfView / 2)  and y will be center of  super view.y = (height / 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
  let imageViewAnimatedFrame: UIImageView = UIImageView()
  imageViewAnimatedFrame.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 159.5, (self.view.frame.size.height / 2) - 149, 391, 298)
```

Divide view's height and width by 2 and divide your imageview's height and width by 2. then subtract half width of imageview from half width of view as position x and same for position y consider height here.

this way your imageview always be in center.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ImageView of these dimensions:

`imageViewAnimatedFrame.size.height = 298`

`imageViewAnimatedFrame.size.width = 391`

```
imageViewAnimatedFrame.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 
imageViewAnimatedFrame.frame.size.width) / 2,
(self.view.frame.size.height -
imageViewAnimatedFrame.frame.size.height) / 2, 
imageViewAnimatedFrame.frame.size.width, imageViewAnimatedFrame.frame.size.height);
```